# Establish a one-to-many relationship between two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I'm using PHP, and SQL to create a small website application for a bake shop. 
I have established 2 data tables:
First one named `Inventory` with columns:

```
itemid INT(Primary key)
itemname text,
volume float,
volume type text (kg,g,lb,L,ml...)
quantity INT.
```

Second one named `Product` with columns:

```
prodid INT Primary Key
prodname TEXT
recipes (don't know which data type yet)
quantity INT.
```

The column `recipes` should contain numerous items from the `inventory` table. My friend wants it that if she make new product, the inventory database will automatically decrease the number of quantities while increasing the quantities

**FOR EXAMPLE:**
If she makes 100 buns(prodname) and the recipe for that 100 buns is
(quantity- itemname)
20- flour,
20- eggs,
10- sugars

then the quantity column in the inventory table should decrease by -20,-20,-10 Where the itemname are flour, eggs, sugars respectively and at the same time the product table with prodname buns should have an increase of 100 in quantity column.

Comment: what is an issue actually?

Comment: Are you asking for the code to implement this or what?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please remove either the SQL Server or MySQL tag.  These different products often require different solutions.  See the faq [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help on posting a question that is likely to get a answer.

Comment: Don't use the `recipes` column like you wrote. Instead, add another table for the recipe for each product - like this: `product_id`, `item_id`, `quantity_for_one_product`. This will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: And be careful with your datatypes here. Not sure which DBMS you are using so this is from a sql server perspective. You have float listed which is not going to work well if you care about accuracy because it is an approximate datatype. Also don't use text as it has been deprecated for more than a decade in favor of varchar(max).